# Sharing post using Facebook Graph API in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm trying to share post using Facebook APIs inside my application , i created an account on Facebook Developer and i put the app id inside the application , the login process is working fine and if i shared a post from the developer Facebook account , every thing is fine . But when i try to share using any other Facebook account i got nothing shared .
I'm using Facebook SDK 3.5 and below are the sharing code:

```
 /**
 * Post message with image
 * 
 * @param imageURl
 */
public void postStatusMessage( byte [] imageURl ) {
    if ( checkPermissions( Session.getActiveSession() ) ) {
        final CustomProgressDialog progress = new CustomProgressDialog( FBActivity.this ) ;
        progress.show() ;

        // Filling the needed data for the share
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle() ;
        parameters.putString( "message" , shareText.getText().toString() ) ; // message
        parameters.putString( "description" , name ) ;// description
        parameters.putString( "link" , linkUrl ) ;// link if available
        parameters.putByteArray( "picture" , imageURl ) ;// byte array for the image so it can be shared as image not as link

        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted( Response response ) {
                if ( response.getError() == null ) {
                    // Share post was done succesfully
                    Toast.makeText( FBActivity.this , getString( R.string.statusUpdateSucc ) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show() ;
                    onlineActionID = ( String ) response.getGraphObject().getProperty( "id" ) ;
                    shareSuccesfuly = true ;

                } else {
                    // Fail in share
                    Toast.makeText( FBActivity.this , "" + getString( R.string.statusUpdateFail ) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show() ;

                }
                // Dismiss progress dialog
                if ( progress.isShowing() )
                    progress.dismiss() ;

                // if share was done sucessfully , navigate back to the previvos page
                if ( shareSuccesfuly ) {
                    finish() ;
                }// end if.
                else {
                    finish() ;
                }// end else().
            }
        } ;

        // Request should have the me/photos tag so we can share photos in the user profile
        Request request = new Request( Session.getActiveSession() , "me/photos" , parameters , HttpMethod.POST , callback ) ;

        request.executeAsync() ;
    } else {
        requestPermissions() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The SDK you are using is very old, I **strongly recommend** you update to the latest release
2. You need to get the permissions needed approved by facebook, see this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)
3. Once done, you need to make your app live from the Status & Review tab
4. You **shouldn't** keep asking users for the publish permission, but instead describe why this is needed, see the [guidelines here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#optimizing).